# Deploying to Windows Phone 10 fails on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, deployment, windows-phone, windows-10

So many things happened that I don't know where to start. Seriously, shouldn't this be simpler?

Edit: Someone here knows how can I contact Microsoft to tell this? Or even, can someone tell them about this problem?

I have the last Windows 10 desktop and also have Windows Phone 10.0.10512.1000. I installed Visual Studio 2015 with tools for Universal Apps development (and also 8.1). I have a Lumia 730.

So I connected my phone with my USB cable. Everything fine, the phone gets recognized and I can navigate through the folders.

Then I started Visual Studio 2015 and created a blank universal app. Compiled and tried to deploy. Now this is happening to me: Visual Studio hangs for some moments. Eventually I get an error telling that the device was not found (DEP6200).

I already tried dozens of solutions:

- disconnecting from wifi in my laptop and my phone
- restarting the IpOverUsbSvc service
- rebooting the computer and the phone
- deleting the devices in the Device Manager
- Registering and Unregistering the phone (it sometimes works)
- All of the above with the phone screen unlocked
- disabling Hyper-V
- disabling firewall
- Other solutions that failed miserably

I also tried to use that Windows Phone Developer Power Tools. When I try to use it, it asks me to install some "Phone Tools Update Pack", but when I try, it says that the operation didn't succeed, and also shows the NRE message string (object reference not set to an instance of an object).

I can go through the phone's folders without any problem. I tried to reinstall the drivers... i tried everything.

It's quite sad.

Do you guys can think of some more thing to check?

EDIT: I tested this app before doing all this: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/09/just-released-windows-10-application-deployment-tool/

And it worked. If that's the case, is Windows Phone 10 deployment over Visual Studio working already or we have to wait some more time?

**Edit2: After making some changes to my app manifest and choosing "ARM" config, now I get this:**

```
1>Deploying to SD Card...
1>Updating the layout...
1>Copying files: Total <1 mb to layout...
1>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
1>Framework: Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0/ARM, app package version 1.0.23117.0 is not currently installed.
1>Framework: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug/ARM, app package version 14.0.23019.0 is not currently installed.
1>Installing missing frameworks...
```

But it just stays there. It's stuck, and it stays there forever. At least I got some info... Its more or less the same steps that WinAppDeployCmd does, but the command line app does it successfully.

Comment: I had this issue. Removing the device from **Devices and Printers** and then uninstalling **Universal Serial Bus devices** worked for me. I am testing my Windows 10 application since a few months starting from VS RC and 10166 build to now using RTM and 10512 build on phone. (Lumia 630)

Comment: Can you provide some more info on how you uninstalled the Universal Serial Bus devices? It's on Device Manager?

Comment: Exactly. My phone shows up as three entries with same name (don't know why?) inside **Universal Serial Bus Devices** categories. Screenshot [here](http://imgur.com/Z1gREJ3)

Comment: Tried uninstalling the drivers and delete the Windows Phone on devices and printers. The problem still happens, Visual Studio hangs violently.

Comment: @RicardoPieper, Does it works now? If yes, please add your solution and make it the Accepted one. It will help other users... like me :-) !

Comment: Nope. I'm using WinAppDeployCmd, but Visual Studio is not working. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please refer to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025133 . These are some know issues for VS2015 so install it properly by reading some instruction from this link. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: No, they don't mention my problem there. I provided some feedback in this page, but my hopes are next to zero. If someone from Microsoft could take a look at this...

Comment: Seriously, how can I contact Microsoft and tell them about this?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody asked that, but does deploying to the emulator works?

Comment: Yes, it works. Also, my phone is in developer mode.

Comment: I've got news. Check my edit2. No success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somehow the problem got solved. I created a brand new project and did this:

1 - In your phone, try disabling the developer mode on your phone. **What an unexpected development!**

2 - Disable the "phone discovery" thingy. I don't know the name of this configuration in english (as my phone is in Portuguese). Just in case.

3 - Choose the correct architecture. This is obvious, right? In my case, ARM. If you try deploying with x86 or x64, **it should give you an error.** For me, it didn't.

From now on, you should be able to deploy your apps in both developer mode and non-developer mode. It just works, somehow. And it might NOT work for you, sorry. I think I got lucky.

It worked even after a reboot. So the solution is "pretty solid" (in an universe where gelatine is pretty solid).

Comment: Not sure your solution actually is the fix, also you shouldnt feel bad about issues with Windows Phone or Visual Studio 2015, both are incredebily buggy.  The reason why I say your solution wasnt the fix, is that many times Visual Studio and WIndows Phone freezes up or Doesnt deploy, sometimes at hours on end, there is no real fix.  Just unplug replug, close/reopen Visual Studio, restart your computer, eventually it will just come back.  Not very scientific but this is what I have observerd, working profesionally with Windows Phone for almost 2 years...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried the fix of the comment and went to devices manager.

Under USB-Devices there were three Lumia 920s listed.

1. I selected the second one and clicked on uninstall.
2. At the end it asked me to restart the Computer. I clicked on NO.

(When I uninstalled the first or third one, it didn't ask me that).
Then the error disappeared (now another common one appears (HRESULT: 0x80073CF6))

Comment: I had the same problem, did a lot of the above as well, and this ended up working for me. For me it was the 3rd one. When I uninstalled it also asked to restart.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lumia 950 xl, with windows 10 installed, anniversary version. I had the same problem, and my solution was to turn on 'Device discovery' and 'Device Portal', and also keep the 'Developer mode' on.

I believe the only necessary option was the 'Device discovery' though!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone still runs into this issue, I had something very similar with my Visual Studio 2015 professional update 1 but I couldn't even deploy to an emulator.
The issue has gone after I upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 update 3.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issues on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015. I updated the the UWP SDK to Anniversary Edition Build 14393, set the target framework to this and it worked. I guess the incompatibility between the device version and sdk version was not allowing the device to be discovered by Visual Studio.