# Deploying UWP app from Visual Studio to Windows 10 Phone requires PIN

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm developing a UWP app for Windows 10 Phone. Since some days when I try to deploy the app from within Visual Studio I get asked for a PIN in order to connect to the device

[image]

In the phone settings I can trigger pairing so a new PIN is generated for me. But when I enter that PIN, a new dialog appears telling that the PIN was wrong:

[image]

If I press 'Cancel' then the deployment is interrupted with an error message:

> 1>Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E'.':

It's strange but some days ago I was not asked for the PIN when I deployed the app. :-( So currently the only option I have is deploy via the web portal. This works but it's enormously slow :-(

Can someone tell me how to solve the problem or what PIN should I enter in order to achieve the deployment?

Comment: Have you tried to restart pairing system? That helped me with a similar problem.

Comment: What means "restart pairing system"? I connect the device with the PC via USB. So the only ting I have to do is register the device as developer device and switch to developer mode.

Comment: I disable device detection and then I enable it, now it shows 0 pairing devices and then I pairing my PC and now it works. Other time I switch off developer mode and then I enable it.

Comment: @ganchito55 what do you mean by 'disable device detection'?

Comment: @Thierry the first option after developer mode in my phone is "device detection" and the description is something like this: enable this feature and this phone will be visible from usb and local network.

Comment: @ganchito55, unfortunately, it didn't work. Will have to leave it for now as it's not my biggest problem! Since yesterday, I can't even deploy to my device while using my USB cable!! So frustrated right now!! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was caused by the fact that I'm developing inside a virtual machine (VMWare Fusion on Mac). After setting up the development ebvironment on a PC the deployment works fine. 
I can even debug the app running on the phone from inside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today, closing visual studio and restarting IpOverUSB service fixed this issue for me.

You might want to take a look at [Ricardo Pieper Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322665/deploying-to-windows-phone-10-fails-on-visual-studio?rq=1) he has listed all the things he tried to do and all the things that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which worked for me:

I had the same problem on my Macbook running VMWare Fusion and trying to debug on my Lumia 950 phone. I was nearly giving up, then I tried using the free VirtualBox and with a virtual USB 3.0 port (which requires the VB extension pack). And it worked!!

Here's my setup:

- VirtualBox 5.0.14
- VB Extension Pack
- Win 10 Development VM from Microsoft – the VirtualBox variant, Build 201601: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/virtual-machines
- Lumia 950 with Windows 10 Mobile 10.0.10586.29

In the VM, I configured to use the USB 3.0 port, since with USB 1.x the phone device driver could not be installed by Windows 10.
The VM contains Visual Studio 2015; I created a UWP JavaScript application and ran it with "Debug" on the connected Lumia device.

Answer (score 0):

Had to go to the Developer options on the device.
Switch back to "Windows Store Apps" option, and then back to "Developer Mode"